# How to prevent two react-native Pickers from affecting each other?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have two Pickers in a react-native View. Whenever, I select the value in one picker, it always causes the other Picker to immediately revert back to the first item in its list. It seems to be calling the onValueChange for both Pickers when I only change the value for one Picker.

The Pickers are set up like this:

```
         <Picker  
          selectedValue={(this.state && this.state.pickerValue) || '30'}
          onValueChange={(value) => {
             this.setState({pickerValue: value});
          }} itemStyle={{color: 'white'}}>

          <Picker.Item label={'30'} value={'30'} />
          <Picker.Item label={'31'} value={'31'} />
          <Picker.Item label={'32'} value={'32'} />
          <Picker.Item label={'33'} value={'33'} />
          <Picker.Item label={'34'} value={'34'} />
          <Picker.Item label={'35'} value={'35'} />
        </Picker>

        <Picker 
          selectedValue={(this.state && this.state.pickerValue) }
          onValueChange={(value) => {
             this.setState({pickerValue: value});
          }} itemStyle={{color: 'white'}}>
          <Picker.Item label={'0'} value={'0'} />
          <Picker.Item label={'1'} value={'1'} />
          <Picker.Item label={'2'} value={'2'} />
          <Picker.Item label={'3'} value={'3'} />
          <Picker.Item label={'4'} value={'4'} />
          <Picker.Item label={'5'} value={'5'} />
        </Picker>
```

Is there any way to prevent the two Pickers from affecting each other?

Comment: The two pickers are doing exactly what you wanted, their value is linked to the same state.pickerValue. You should use 2 state value OR abstract each Picker inside individual Component that hold his own state

Comment: How do I go about using 2 states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same state property to store the value of both pickers, you can save them in different properties like **pickerValueA** and **pickerValueB**

Something like this.

```
constructor(props){
   this.state = {
      pickerValueA: '' // Your initial value here
      pickerValueB: '' // Your initial value here
   }
}

<Picker  
      selectedValue={this.state.pickerValueA}
      onValueChange={(value) => {
         this.setState({pickerValueA: value});
      }} itemStyle={{color: 'white'}}>

      <Picker.Item label={'30'} value={'30'} />
      <Picker.Item label={'31'} value={'31'} />
      <Picker.Item label={'32'} value={'32'} />
      <Picker.Item label={'33'} value={'33'} />
      <Picker.Item label={'34'} value={'34'} />
      <Picker.Item label={'35'} value={'35'} />
</Picker>
<Picker 
      selectedValue={this.state.pickerValueB}
      onValueChange={(value) => {
         this.setState({pickerValueB: value});
      }} itemStyle={{color: 'white'}}>
      <Picker.Item label={'0'} value={'0'} />
      <Picker.Item label={'1'} value={'1'} />
      <Picker.Item label={'2'} value={'2'} />
      <Picker.Item label={'3'} value={'3'} />
      <Picker.Item label={'4'} value={'4'} />
      <Picker.Item label={'5'} value={'5'} />
    </Picker>
```

Comment: In this `(this.state && this.state.pickerValueA)`, is this line adding attributes to the state object?

Comment: You should set up your initial state in your constructor, I edited the answer.